# Instant update of the date variable for ngIf - Angular 2

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, angular8

There is a dropdown menu on my order card. There is a cancel button in this menu. The user can cancel the order within the first 10 minutes after creating it. I am using Moment.js package to compare dates.

order-card.component.ts

```
canBeCanceled = false;

ngOnInit() {
    this.canBeCanceled = moment().diff(order.createdAt, 'minutes', true) > 10;
}
```

order-card.compenent.html

```
<button *ngIf="canBeCanceled">Cancel</button>
```

When the page is first opened, everything will work fine, but if the user stays active on the page for more than 10 minutes, the button will not be hidden. I'm looking for a solution where I can change the variable instantly and hide the button instantly. Maybe with RxJS etc.

Comment: RXJS would work for what you're looking for. You should post you attempt at coding the solution yourself and we can help if you run into problems.

Comment: @anthonyb  I've looked through the RxJS docs but didn't know how best to use it. I'll try anyway, thanks.

Comment: If this question is about Angular 2, why did you give it an Angular 8 tag?

Comment: set a ten minute timer that flips a boolean?

Comment: @KenWhite there are two variants of the Angular Framework: AngularJS (v1) and Angular (v2+). The term “Angular 2” is often used to distinguish from AngularJS, meaning any version 2 or newer.

Comment: Don't use moment, it is deprecated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could make `canBeCanceled` an observable that emits `true` initially, then emits `false` after 10 minutes.  Of course if the "latest cancel time" is in the past, we only want to emit `false`:

```js
this.canBeCanceled$ = moment().diff(latestCancelTime) < 0
  ? concat(of(true), of(false).pipe(delay(latestCancelTime)))
  : of(false);
```

```html
<button *ngIf="canBeCanceled$ | async">Cancel</button>
```

Here's a little [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/so-73902615?file=src%2Fapp%2Forder-card%2Forder-card.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Forder-card%2Forder-card.component.ts) example.

Comment: You can change `canBeCanceled$` to this `timer(latestCancelTime).pipe(map(() => true))`
ngIf to this `<button *ngIf="!(canBeCanceled$ | async)">Cancel</button>`
https://stackblitz.com/edit/so-73902615-3bbflj

Comment: Doing so causes the button to initially appear then quickly disappear when the date is in the past.  This is because we would be relying on absence of an emission to indicate the button should be shown. It's more reliable to rely on an explicit boolean emission that expresses the correct state based on the condition.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use setTimeout method to achieve this.

```
// initially button is visible
canBeCanceled = true;

ngOnInit() {
    // 10000 is milliseconds which is 10 seconds
    setTimeout(()=>{
       // this line will be run after 10 seconds
       this.canBeCanceled = false;
    }, 10000)
}
```